# unity2d rotation of a gameobject along z axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I am looking for a simple solution of rotating a 2d object along z axis clockwise/anticlockwise on touch gesture.

This is what i tried but its not working properly

Here's the code snippet :

```
 void OnMouseDown()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    baseAngle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    baseAngle -= Mathf.Atan2(transform.right.y, transform.right.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(transform.position);
    pos = Input.mousePosition - pos;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(pos.y, pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - baseAngle;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us, how it is not working properly?

Comment: Its not smooth enough and its rotation depends upon in which quadrant is it placed .

Comment: How do you want the rotation to work? Do you want to rotate object when user drags the finger say left and right? Or should the object face in the direction of the finger?

Comment: @Smilediver : The first Concept .. I mean if i drag my finger left,it should rotate anticlockwise and clockwise for dragging my finger right

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
Vector3 oldMousePos;

void OnMouseDown()
{
    oldMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 diff = Input.mousePosition - oldMousePos;
    oldMousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    float angle = diff.x * rotationSpeed;
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, angle);
}
```

Another way

```
void OnUpdate()
{
    float angle = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationSpeed;
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, angle);
}
```

You can change Vector3.forward to change the axis, around which the rotation should happen. And you can tweak rotationSpeed to change how much object should rotate.

Answer (score 0):

Click on object and drag to rotate it to the direction you want.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DragRotate : MonoBehaviour {

  [Header("Degree of rotation offset. *360")]
  public float offset = 180.0f;

  Vector3 startDragDir;
  Vector3 currentDragDir;
  Quaternion initialRotation;
  float angleFromStart;

  void OnMouseDown(){

     startDragDir = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;

     initialRotation = transform.rotation;
  }


  void OnMouseDrag(){
    Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;

    difference.Normalize();


    float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotationZ - (90 + offset));
  }
}
```